# C# 2 bindingList in format listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I'm trying to add a second BindingList to a ListBox but can't figure out how. Here is my code.

```
private Entitycontext context = new Entitycontext();
private BindingList<TblProduct> products = new BindingList<TblProduct>(); 
private BindingList <TblProductItem> SubProduct = new BindingList <TblProductItem>();

public form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   // here in listbox i want to add the second BindingList but I don't Know how??
   // Could some One help me with this please..
   ListBox.DataSource = Products;
}

/// here the listbox is format as FormaLIstItem
private void FormaLIstItem(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
   string currentDescription = ((TblProduct)e.ListItem).Description.PadRight(25);
   string currentPrice = string.Format("{0:C}"((TblProduct)e.ListItem).Price).PadRight(25);
   e.Value =  currentDescription + currentPrice;
   string currentDescriptions = ((TblProductItem)e.Value).Description.PadRight(25);
   string currentPrices = string.Format("{0:C}",((TblProductItem)e.Value).Price).PadRight(25);
   e.Value =  currentDescriptions + currentPrices;
}
```

Comment: Does the Products list currently appear correctly in your ListBox? Are you trying to add an "expanded" list of sorts so that each Product has an indented sub-list of SubProducts?

Comment: yes but all the buttons with contents they are in tabcontrol so now  i just add another tabcontrol and i want to  use the same listbox . so is a  way that can i collect both?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Just looking at your code I see a few problems here. Your FormaLIstItem (I think FormatListItem) sets e.Value twice, so only the second e.Value setter gets applied. Have you considered just having one list of Products with a property that indicates whether it's a subproduct or not? You could then check that property and format the description to include an indentation, which I think would give you the same effect.

Comment: yes do you know how can i get that reference